iPhone 15 Pro Max Camera Ignores deviceId and Switches Between Lenses Automatically in React Apps
I’m building a web app that uses the camera for document scanning and have noticed strange behavior on the iPhone 15 Pro Max. The phone seems to:
1.  Select a default camera (likely the main wide-angle lens).
2.  Automatically switch to a wider camera lens when focusing on an object.
Even when I explicitly provide a deviceId in the videoConstraints, this behavior persists. Changing the deviceId dynamically also doesn’t work—the camera defaults to the same lens and continues to switch automatically during use.
This results in noticeable flickering due to the abrupt change in resolution and field of view.
I’ve tested this in a React environment with both react-webcam and react-camera-pro, and the behavior is consistent.
you can test this in both demo apps:
1 - react-camera-pro
2 - react-webcam
Here’s a simplified version of my setup:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import Webcam from 'react-webcam';

const CameraComponent = () => {
  const [selectedDeviceId, setSelectedDeviceId] = useState<string>();

  const handleDevices = useCallback((devices: MediaDeviceInfo[]) => {
    const videoDevices = devices.filter(({ kind }) => kind === 'videoinput');
    if (videoDevices.length > 0) {
      setSelectedDeviceId(videoDevices[0].deviceId); // Explicitly set the first device
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(handleDevices);
  }, [handleDevices]);

  return (
    <Webcam
      audio={false}
      videoConstraints={{
        deviceId: selectedDeviceId ? { exact: selectedDeviceId } : undefined,
      }}
      screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
    />
  );
};

export default CameraComponent;

This behavior doesn’t occur on Android or older iPhones with a single rear camera.
What I’ve Tried:
•   Explicitly setting the deviceId in videoConstraints.
•   Dynamically changing the deviceId during the camera feed.
•   Using different React libraries (react-webcam and react-camera-pro).

My Question:
1.  Why does iOS override the deviceId and switch between cameras automatically?
2.  Is there any way to force iOS to stick to a specific lens without automatic switching?
3.  How can I prevent the flickering caused by the lens change during scanning?

Any insights or workarounds would be appreciated!
